# Foreign key not null in database, but is null in View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on a Twitter clone using ASP.net, Entity Framework and Code First. I used [this](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) tutorial to get started with the EF, since I don't have any experience with it. All goes well until I want to get the author of the "tweet" placed.

This is my kweet model class:

```
public class Kweet
{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public KwetterUser Author { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public string PostedFrom { get; set; }

    public DateTime Timeplaced { get; set; }
}
```

This is my user model class:

```
    public class KwetterUser
{
    public int KwetterUserID { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Realname { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; }

    public string Web { get; set; }

    public string Bio { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Kweet> kweets { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Follow> follow { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code used to send the list of Kweets to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Kweets.ToList());
}
```

This is the code used to get the Author of the Kweet:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author.Username)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Timeplaced)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

The weird thing is, when I check my database with the Server Explorer everything is filled with the correct data. The KwetterUserID's are in the Author field etc. So I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate on "doesn't work".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the following fix your issue?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Kweets.Include(k=>k.Author).ToList());
}
```

If it does, have a look at the [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) about eagerly loading related data. The relevant parts are:
Entity Framework supports three ways to load related data - eager loading, lazy loading and explicit loading.

**Eagerly Loading**

Eager loading is the process whereby a query for one type of entity also loads related entities as part of the query. Eager loading is achieved by use of the Include method. For example, the queries below will load blogs and all the posts related to each blog.

```
/ Load all blogs and related posts 
var blogs1 = context.Blogs 
                      .Include(b => b.Posts) 
                      .ToList();
```

**Lazy Loading**

Lazy loading is the process whereby an entity or collection of entities is automatically loaded from the database the first time that a property referring to the entity/entities is accessed. When using POCO entity types, lazy loading is achieved by creating instances of derived proxy types and then overriding virtual properties to add the loading hook.

**Explicitly Loading**

Even with lazy loading disabled it is still possible to lazily load related entities, but it must be done with an explicit call. To do so you use the Load method on the related entity’s entry. For example:

```
var post = context.Posts.Find(2); 

// Load the blog related to a given post 
context.Entry(post).Reference(p => p.Blog).Load();
```

Comment: This should help, but you should also add some words for the why it helps ;o)

Comment: I just added some more details and a link in case that really was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Selecting only the variables you want into a viewmodel will be more efficient.

```
  db.Kweets.Select(c => new KweetList()
    {
         Content = c.Content,
         AuthorName = c.Author.Username,
         TimePlaced = c.TimePlaced
    }).ToList()
```